# how to use ubuntu desktop as a mail server?

Tags: server, mail, mail-server

I'm a open source web developer and I'm just using ubuntu 11.10 x64 desktop version as my web server by installing PHP MySQl and Apache 2. I mainly use PHP to send email from my web server. But I wish to receive and store message from others or from my coding via internet.So, I wish to know how to use ubuntu as my mail server ? Please reply me...

Thank all geeks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mailservers to choose from. Full featured beasts like `postfix` or `sendmail` for example. On a desktop machine I would recommend `exim4` as it is relatively easy to configure. Just

`apt-get install exim4`

to install. A configuration wizard should start automatically after installation. If not, start it with

`dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`